# Can’t see widget areas in my Theme Customize (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, widget

I’ve a problem with my Theme Customize.
I’ve registered 4 widget area in my template, I can see them correctly in the Apparence > Widget panel, but I can’t see them in the Theme Customize, when I click on my Widget section I have the following message instead:

**Your theme has 4 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them. You can navigate to other pages on your site while using the Customizer to view and edit the widgets displayed on those pages.**

For example, i want to use sidebar at other pages, but it only shows on the shop page.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Thank you all.